# Is $ 5 $ nearer to $ 0 $ or $ 10 $?

Tags: arithmetic, education

My 6-year-old’s homework was “to find the nearest $ 10 $.” For example,
$$
42 \to 40 \quad \text{and} \quad 28 \to 30.
$$
For $ 55 $, she answered “$ 50 $” and was marked wrong. How is this wrong? Clearly, $ 55 $ is slap-bang in the middle of $ 50 $ and $ 60 $, so surely either answer is correct. The question does not mention rounding of any sort, therefore you can’t say that common rounding is being used. Comments are most welcome!

Comment: What metric space did the teacher specify?

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, very interesting to hear all your opinions. What concerns me is that 6 year olds are being taught that 5 is closer to 10 than it is to zero. Does this mean when they are 5 miles through a ten mile walk they will think that it's further to walk back the way they came than to carry on? I feel like I'm missing something here!

Comment: Perhaps he was expected to answer $\{50, 60\}$?

Comment: @Nit, its unlikely for a 6 year old's homework...

Comment: Was it a large amount of "5". So she expected 60... in small amounts of "5" I could understand answering 50...

Comment: The main lesson here is that the teacher likely taught and gave examples of rounding 5 up to 10 in response to questions like this, so the 'correct' answer was to answer in accordance with those examples.  This is less a lesson in mathematics and more a lesson in understanding and meeting personal expectations for the purpose of achieving a goal (a good score on the test.)  The approach being taught may well be flawed, but being able to tolerate doing things incorrectly for the sake of expediency is perhaps a valuable life skill.  Then again, maybe not...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

$$|55-50|=5 \\
|55-60|=5 \\
5=5$$
QED

Comment: tongue a little bit in cheek here ;)

Comment: I wish all proofs were so easy.

Answer (score 15):

I would agree with you that both answers should be correct.  Despite your plea not to mention common rounding, I suspect that is where the problem is-the answer key was made up with "round 5 to even" or "round 5 up" in mind.

Comment: Also, it seems logical as a convention to have 5 rounded to 10, as if we divide the numbers 0-9 into two halves, it would have to be 0-1-2-3-4 and 5-6-7-8-9 to have the same number of numbers in each half.

Comment: Yep, but if the question was formulated as "find the nearest", the question is bogus as there are two nearest.

Comment: @Hippalectryon That argument is not correct, because numbers end in 0 are not rounded at all, neither up nor down.  So you are rounding numbers ending in digit 1-2-3-4 down, and those ending in 5-6-7-8-9 up, and this does *in fact* bias the results upward. (To see this, generate ten thousand random numbers, and sum them; then round each one off to the nearest integer, and sum them again. The second sum will invariably exceed the first.) This is why persons who deal seriously with statistics adopt a different rule, such as round-toward-even.

Comment: @MJD Ooh that's true

Comment: @MJD You should be careful with the word "invariably" in mathematics. There are (very unlikely) cases where the two sums are equal, e.g. when each random number is already an integer.

Comment: @TimS. Good luck generating 10,000 random real numbers and having them all come out to be integers -- get back to us when that works out! ;)

Answer (score 7):

This is probably an exercise on rounding, where if the one's place is greater than or equal to $5$, then rounding up is considered "correct" (although if you study statistics at a high level, you will find out that this is not the case; there are different rules). However, the question said "find the nearest", in which case both answers are correct. The question in the homework is pretty ambiguous, and IMHO should not be asked.

Getting back to the main question, let's examine the differences between $0$ and $5$, and $5$ and $10$.

$0$ is exactly $5$ away from the number $5$, and so is $10$. The number $5$ is right in the middle of $0$ and $10$. It is not closer to any of the numbers.

$$\underbrace{0, \ 1, \ 2, \ 3, \ 4,}_{\text{5 numbers}} \ \mathbf 5, \ \underbrace{6, \ 7, \ 8, \ 9, \ 10}_{\text{5 numbers}}$$

Imagine a race is held in a $10\text{km}$ straightaway. One car starts at the very left (i.e. at $0$ km) and the other starts at the very right (i.e. at $10$ km). Both cars have to travel $5$ km to the finish line. If they both travel at the exact same speed throughout the race, then obviously they will get there in the exact same time!

[image: Racing on a 10 km straightaway]

The point of that was to say that the difference between $0$ and $5$, and $5$ and $10$ are the same! There's no "$0$ is closer to $5$" or any of that stuff.

**$5$ is as close to $0$ as it is close to $10$.**

Comment: this answer currently violates the answers with pictures get lots of votes principle. curious.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook My drawings suck haha

Answer (score 2):

You're right that it's ambiguous so there is a long-standing convention that you always round the 5 up.

Comment: As the question rightly says, this is not deemed to be a rounding.

Comment: Clearly it *is* deemed to be a rounding, by the marking scheme. The question is to assemble ammunition to challenge the marking scheme and change how it's deemed ;-)

Comment: It might have just been the case that the question isn't saying what it's really asking.